# input field not being aligned center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Need your help

I am a beginner in web development

**Can you explain why the input field is not aligning in center ?**

`<"input type="text" id="search_bar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" align="center">`

In the CSS I tried adding `"float:center;"` at multiple places in the CSS related to the input field but nothing seems to work at all.

here's the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Login and Signup Form with Social Buttons</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  margin:0px;
 }
 .form-control {
  box-shadow: none;  
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
 }
 .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #33cabb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 }
 .navbar-header.col {
  padding: 0 !important;
 } 
 .navbar {
  background: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 }
 .nav-link img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: -8px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
 .navbar .form-inline {
        display: inline-block;
    }
 .navbar .nav li {
  position: relative;
 }
 .navbar .nav li a {
  color: #888;
 }
 .search-box {
  float: center;
    } 
    .search-box input {
     float: center;
  border-color: #dfe3e8;
        border-radius: 20px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
    }
 .search-box .input-group-addon {
  float: center;
        min-width: 35px;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9;
        padding: 7px;
  height: 100%;
    }
    .search-box i {
        color: #a0a5b1;
  font-size: 19px;
    }
 .navbar .nav .btn-primary, .navbar .nav .btn-primary:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #33cabb;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
 } 
 .navbar .nav .btn-primary:hover, .navbar .nav .btn-primary:focus {  
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: #31bfb1;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-right li:first-child a {
  padding-right: 30px;
 }
 .navbar .nav-item i {
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .navbar .dropdown-item i {
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 22px;
 }
 .navbar ul.nav li.active a, .navbar ul.nav li.open > a {
  background: transparent !important;
 } 
 .navbar .nav .get-started-btn {
  min-width: 120px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
 }
 .navbar ul.nav li.open > a.get-started-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #31bfb1 !important;
 }
 .navbar .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
 }
 .navbar .nav .dropdown-menu li {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
 }
 .navbar .nav .dropdown-menu li a, .navbar .nav .dropdown-menu li a:hover, .navbar .nav .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  line-height: normal;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-form {
  border: none;
 }
 .navbar .dropdown-menu.form-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 20px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
 }
 .navbar .dropdown-menu.form-wrapper a {  
  color: #33cabb;
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .navbar .dropdown-menu.form-wrapper a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
 .navbar .form-wrapper .hint-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
 }
 .navbar .form-wrapper .social-btn .btn, .navbar .form-wrapper .social-btn .btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 34px;
  width: 47%;
  text-decoration: none;
    } 
 .navbar .social-btn .btn-primary {
  background: #507cc0;
 }
 .navbar .social-btn .btn-primary:hover {
  background: #4676bd;
 }
 .navbar .social-btn .btn-info {
  background: #64ccf1;
 }
 .navbar .social-btn .btn-info:hover {
  background: #4ec7ef;
 }
 .navbar .social-btn .btn i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
 }
 .navbar .form-wrapper .form-footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
 }
 .navbar .form-wrapper .form-footer a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
 .navbar .form-wrapper .checkbox-inline input {
  margin-top: 3px;
 }
 .or-seperator {
        margin-top: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    .or-seperator b {
  color: #666;
        padding: 0 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
    }
    .navbar .checkbox-inline {
  font-size: 13px;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-right .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
 }
 @media (min-width: 1200px){
  .form-inline .input-group {
   width: 300px;
   margin-left: 30px;
  }
 }
 @media (max-width: 768px){
  .navbar .dropdown-menu.form-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
  }
  .navbar .form-inline {
   display: block;
  }
  .navbar .input-group {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar .nav .btn-primary, .navbar .nav .btn-primary:active {
   display: block;
  }
 }
 .B{
  margin-top: 0px;
 height: 40px;
 width:65px;
 float: top;
 margin-top: 10px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.C{
 display:inline-block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Prevent dropdown menu from closing when click inside the form
 $(document).on("click", ".navbar-right .dropdown-menu", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
 <div class="navbar-header d-flex col"><img src="logo.png" class="B" alt="logo">   
  <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler ml-auto">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
  <form class="navbar-form form-inline">
   <div class="input-group search-box" align="center">        
    <input type="text" id="search_bar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" align="center">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i></span>
   </div>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto">   
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Login</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu form-wrapper">     
     <li>
      <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
       <p class="hint-text">Sign in with your social media account</p>
       <div class="form-group social-btn clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
       </div>
       <div class="or-seperator"><b>or</b></div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
       </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
       <div class="form-footer">
        <a href="#">Forgot Your password?</a>
       </div>
      </form>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle get-started-btn mt-1 mb-1">Sign up</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu form-wrapper">     
     <li>
      <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" method="post">
       <p class="hint-text">Fill in this form to create your account!</p>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" required="required"> I accept the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></label>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign up">
      </form>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please read the article on how to provide a [mre]. The amount of code presented here is certainly not minimal. I encourage all beginners to look at documentation to see what possible attributes and values are. For instance [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) does not have an `align` attribute on it, and [`float` does not allow "center" as a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Values).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here that you like to have the placeholder in the input field in the center.
If this is the case, try:

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the input field within a block element and set that parent element to have `text-align:center;`.

That way you can control where you want the item to be positioned relative to the div (block element)

Answer (score 1):

the navbar containing the form element should center its child elements.

```
.navbarCollapse{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different id for label and different id for textfield. Then you can easily manage them through css.